# Error in compiling caffe on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: compilation, deep-learning, caffe

I need to use the Single Shot Multibox Detector implemented in Caffe. After cloning the repository, I've switched to the correct branch and I've installed all the dependencies required (by following the guide on caffe website). Unfortunately, when I compile at certain point I get this error:

```
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to "boost::re_detail_106200::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const"
```

But boost is installed. How can I resolve?

Comment: Check your library path variable(s).  Also, try posting the problem under the Caffe support site.

Comment: @Prune I've checked the library path and it's included in the makefile.config. I will try again and let you know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add boost_regex to `LIBRARIES` variable in Makefile in case you use Makefile.config compilation, or to `find_package(Boost 1.54 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread filesystem)` line in caffe/cmake/Dependencies.cmake